# What is the best way to load-manipulate-update picture/pixels?

Tags: java, bitmap, pixel, bufferedimage, raster

There's BufferedImage (btw, is it the best way to store and edit frame's graphics?) and function that does some editing to this image.

My current approach:

```
 //usage: 
image.setData(update(image.getRaster()));


public Raster update(WritableRaster raster) {
    int[] pixels = new int[raster.getWidth() * raster.getHeight()];
    raster.getDataElements(0, 0, w, h, pixels); // raster to int[]
  //pixels array operations      
    raster.setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, pixels); // int[] to raster
    return raster;
}
```

Sending raster seems to be a bottleneck of this approach but what are the other options?

Comment: You can write pixels directly to the BufferedImage using [setRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29). Unless you have profiled a specific pixel operation and found this to be a bottleneck, optimizing this seems premature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write efficiently into any pixel in the image by storing color values directly in the raster. The most performant way I've found to dynamically manipulate images this way is like this:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(inputWidth, inputHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        int[] rgbRaster = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        for(int i = 0; i < inputHeight; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < inputWidth; j++) {
                int index = (inputWidth  * i) + j;
                rgbRaster[index] = SOME_ARG_VALUE;
                }
            }
        }
```

Of course you don't have to recreate the image or raster array over and over, just create them once, and write into the array when you want to. Pretty fast, and pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for help.
Check out result at your will.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISKOBmh_sqM
http://textuploader.com/xj7j

Comment: Wish you marked mine as answer if it helped. AFAIK, its the fastest method to dynamically update BufferedImages in java. Nice effects though, - a typical case for direct raster manipulation. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck in your code is actually `image.setData(...)`, because it will *copy all data* from the `Raster` into your image (even if you only modified a single pixel in the `update(...)` method).

However, this is completely unnecessary in this case, as the `WritableRaster` returned by `image.getRaster()` represents a "live view" to the pixels. Simply using:

```
update(image.getRaster());
```

...should do, and be much faster.

If you know that your image is `TYPE_INT_*` you can do as @Terje suggests, and access the underlying data buffer directly. This might be even faster. Note that the pixel array is also a "live view", so any changes to the array will be reflected in the image.

```
int[] rgb = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Both of these methods might make the image slower to display (aka "unmanaged"), but for general image processing, they should be fine.

Comment: Assuming that class creates with parameters including image heres strange behaviour I've found:
Update() works only with constructor-created image and method-created int[];
Update2(BufferedImage) works with both image and int[] creted in this method;
Update3() works with both image and int[] created in constructor;
Obviously update3 is the fastest BUT update2 is somehow faster than update1.

Comment: @abvgde I'm sorry, still don't understand... Have you edited your question to add new `update` methods? If so, I can't see them, so I have no idea what those look like...

Comment: It's okay, nevermind. I'm quite bad at descriptions. You can check out what it was for, link for video and class is in other comment section. Thanks for help.